# blocking ports windows prompt hidden

Tags: windows-server-2003

I want to block a port via cmd prompt so that my students does not re-open it via the windows firewall app. I want to block port 22 from Windows command prompt... Any kind of help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why should the students have the permission to alter the firewall in the first place?

Comment: they all are logged in as administrator... just a few computers setup to do minor admin stuff, just want to block a port that is not visible in the windows firewall gui/app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this via Group Policy. There is nothing magical about the command prompt that makes things irreversible if done there. Any rule you make with `netsh` can be undone from the GUI. Because they're admins and have physical access, they can even get around the GPO if they're persistent enough.

Moral of the story: you can use GPO to put hurdles in their path, but they can get around them if they have admin rights.